# Rate limit of Solana Airdrop on devnet

Tags: devnet, airdrop

I am running a script on devnet with a regular interval that requires solana airdrop.

Now I get `Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached.`

So I was wondering, does anyone know what the limit is? I.e. is there a fixed limit per time unit or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your maximum limit to airdrop has been reached. Maximum 24 SOL are allowed per day. This limit is set so users may not abuse the devnet. You can airdrop SOL to different accounts and use it there or transfer it to the currently blocked account. The SOL airdrop limit will reset the next day and you can airdrop up to 24 SOL again.

Answer (score 2):

The devnet airdrop is capped at 2 Sol per request. And there is a fixed limit time as well and it appears to be about 5 seconds (may be more/less but not by much).

Comment: Airdrop 2 SOL per every 5 seconds? That does not sound right. I tried airdropping 2 SOL every hour and got rate limited